# R - xmlnodeset output into dataframe or table

Tags: r, csv, xmlnode, rvest

I'm trying to save html code chunk in csv file rows from two different pages.

1. Took two links
2. Use loop to visit the links and select two html code chunks using rvest
3. print them using sapply
4. Want to print the output in a row in csv file ( Need help on this)

I can see the html chunks in console but can't save them in csv .. I want to save the html code rather than values. I used IMDB just for code replication purpose.

```
library(rvest   
 movielinks <- c("http://www.imdb.com/movies-coming-soon/?ref_=inth_cs", "http://www.imdb.com/movies-in-theaters/?ref_=nv_tp_inth_1")


     moviesheet <- NULL

    for (mov in 1: length(movielinks)) {

       #print(mov)
       pageurl <- paste0(movielinks[mov])
       # print(pageurl)

       movieurl <- html(pageurl)

   movie_name <- movieurl %>% 
     html_nodes("h4 a ")# %>%       # find all links



   strings<-paste(sapply(movie_name, function(x) { print(x) }))
   moviesheet <- rbind(moviesheet, strings)

}
write.csv(moviesheet, "moviesheet.csv")
```

Final Outcome is something like this

```
Product Price HtmlCode
Soap     20     <a href="/title/tt3691740/?ref_=cs_ov_tt" title="
                 The BFG (2016)" 
                  itemprop="url"> The BFG (2016)</a>
```

Comment: #1 The [ToU of imdb.com](http://www.imdb.com/conditions) say: _"You may not use data mining, robots, screen scraping, or similar data gathering and extraction tools on this site, except with our express written consent as noted below. "_. #2 You may need `strings<-movieurl %>% html_nodes("h4 a ") %>% html_attr("href")`.

Comment: I just took couple of pages so that anybody can replicate the code rather than scraping something from imdb. What I want to do is save the data from a project for later use. I want to save html code for later use rather than values.

Comment: Anyway, `read_html("http://www.imdb.com/movies-in-theaters/?ref_=nv_tp_inth_1") %>% html_nodes("h4 a") %>% as.character` would give you a character representation of the nodeset's HTML.

Comment: It shows error both ways - if I read with html (rvest) then I can use as.character and if I use read_html (xml2) then I have error in html_nodes

Comment: The above code does not show any error, here. Maybe update your packages.

Comment: Cool mate, it seems to work. Awesome help.